# Custom form validator fails in Angular 1.3 with $timeout and $setValidity

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I made myself a custom validator, that works exactly as I want with `AngularJS 1.2` but now I would like to upgrade to the latest and almost stable version of `1.3` but after debugging for some time I found that it doesn't work as expected because I use both `$timeout` with inside a `ctrl.$setValidity`. My original and working code (of course it's just a subset of the actual code) is the following:

```
var validator = function(value) { 
    // invalidate field before doing any validation, 
    // so that it's invalid before typing timeout has time to finish and execute 
    ctrl.$setValidity('validation', false);

    $timeout.cancel(timer);            
    timer = $timeout(function() {  
        var isValid = validate(value);
        ctrl.$setValidity('validation', isValid);
    }, 1500);

    return value;        
}; // end of validator()

// attach the Validator object to the element
ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validator);
ctrl.$formatters.unshift(validator);
```

I manually change the `$setValidity` to `false` because I want to make sure that the user will not post the form before the field is actually finished validated. The timeout is there only so that it gives the user a smoother experience by displaying the error (if there is) only after he finished typing (or at least stop typing after 1.5sec). After that timeout of 1.5sec is finished, the `validate(value)` kicks in and should update the `$setValidity` to true or false... This is working perfectly fine in `AngularJS 1.2` but not at all in `1.3`. Even if I manually set the `$setValidity` to `true` by myself it doesn't work and actually stays to a `false` state, but if I remove the `$timeout` wrapper, then it's working fine.... but I really need and want my timeout to work! 
For a reference point of view, my custom validator is available freely to anyone at this [Github link](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-validation)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT
After having help from @SKYWALKR (thanks for starting help), I further went to debug my problem and it is actually much more than what I described at first. My problem seems in fact related to a bunch of things all together, `ng-model` binding inside `ng-repeat` that execute a custom validator which has problem **only** if I enable the `$timeout`... now with all that together, the binding does not function correctly, wow took me a while to build a proper testing case for this. So here is the sample of my problem:
 [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RJaIOIHhvTgkehEgFUVi)
When you run the sample at first, you will see that none of the Output A:{{binding}} is working (it's suppose to display whatever you type just below it) that it does not work, but then if you comment out the `var timer` and `$timeout` (comment out line 39, 42 and 44) and then run it again, now it works...so why? what's broken?

Answer (score 1):

Your correct, 1.3 is not a stable release as of yet. Your directive works fine using 1.3.0-rc.0...see plunkr below.

http://embed.plnkr.co/GSU2Ldn0D2YM0aD9PQla/preview

Comment: hmm yes you are right, it does work.. and I might have looked in the wrong direction. Instead the problem seems more like the binding, the `ng-model` does not return my value in the controller. So basically I have my custom validator, and once it's finish validating does a `ng-change` event, from then after takes the value of the ng-model, but it returns `undefined`, if I remove the `$timeout` I do get the value as usual... even in your plunkr, I can't get the binding on screen. Sorry about going in a different direction, you know debugging world :S

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I forked your plunker and created another big beast of my actual problem. I edited my question, it's a lot bigger problem than I expected..again thx for help!